# Vagrant+Docker: The container started never left the "stopped" state

Tags: docker, vagrant, anaconda, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I'm trying to write a deployable data science environment that runs the `continuumio/anaconda3` Docker container within a `ubuntu/trusty64` Vagrant box. This seems to run fine however the container shuts down immediately.  Following the docs [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3/) I've tried passing the `d.run` and `d.cmd` commands to no success.  I'd like to be able to do the Vagrant equivalent of passing the Docker command

```
docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser"
```

so that I can access the notebook from `localhost:8888` (I've already done something similar with Apache httpd by following [this guide](http://scalarsoftware.com/setting-up-a-development-environment-with-vagrant-and-docker/)).  Unfortunately I just can't seem to get the syntax right for this, any help would be appreciated.

I have included my HostVagrantfile and Vagrantfile below.

**HostVagrantfile:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Specify Vagrant version, Vagrant API version, and Vagrant clone location
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

# Create and configure the VM(s)
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # Use Docker provisioner
  config.vm.provision "docker"

  # Workaround
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline:
     "ps aux | grep 'sshd:' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill"

  # Assign a friendly name to this host VM
  config.vm.hostname = "docker"

  config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8888, host: 8888

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
end
```

**Vagrantfile:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Specify Vagrant version and Vagrant API version
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'

# Create and configure the Docker container(s)
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.define "apache" do |a|

    a.vm.provider "docker" do |d|

      d.image = "continuumio/anaconda3"
      d.name = "anacond3-container"
      d.ports = ["80:80", "433:443", "8888:8888"]
      d.remains_running = true
      d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "HostVagrantfile"
    end
  end
end
```

**Update**
This is the result I get when trying to run:

`$ vagrant docker-run -i -t -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser"`

```
An invalid option was specified. The help for this command
is available below.

Usage: vagrant docker-run [command...]

Options:

        --[no-]detach                Run in the background
    -t, --[no-]tty                   Allocate a pty
    -r, --[no-]rm,                   Remove container after execution
    -h, --help                       Print this help
```

Comment: did you try to run `vagrant docker-run -it apache -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 -- /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser"`

Comment: I've updated the question with the output of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out myself in the end.  Needed to break the docker run command

```
docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser"
```

using the vagrant docker run, args, cmd commands after pulling the images.  Instead of using

```
config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
  d.image = "continuumio/anaconda3"
end
```

use

```
config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
  d.pull_images "continuumio/anaconda3"
  d.run "continuumio/anaconda3",
    args: "-t -p 8888:8888",
    cmd: $jupyterServer
end
```

and define

```
$jupyterServer = <<SCRIPT
/bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser"
SCRIPT
```

I also combined the two Vagrantfiles into one:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Specify Vagrant version, Vagrant API version
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

$jupyterServer = <<SCRIPT
/bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser"
SCRIPT

# Create and configure the VM(s)
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
  end

  # Use Docker provisioner
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.pull_images "continuumio/anaconda3"
    d.run "continuumio/anaconda3",
      args: "-t -p 8888:8888",
      cmd: $jupyterServer
  end

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8888, host: 8888
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
end
```